# Free editable grid for commercial use

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a free grid which can display and edit data in a web page and whose license permits the use in commercial products. It will be used in an ASP.NET WebForms app.

I have found some and I am looking for more:

- Sencha EXTJS the last free edition (2.3)
- [editablegrid.net](http://www.editablegrid.net/)
- https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki

Comment: Why are you looking for more? What is missing in those three that you are still looking for? This is not "can you make a list for me" or "can you compare these products for me" site. Please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information and http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-to-ask-for-an-alternative-to-some-software and [edit] your question to ask for **a** software recommendation. You may still get more than one.

Comment: It doesn't matter anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Essential Grid for ASP.NET](http://asp.syncfusion.com/demos/web/grid/defaultfunctionalities.aspx) supports displaying and editing data. It is available for free in commercial applications also through the [community license program](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense). There are JavaScript and ASP.NET MVC variants of the Grid also.
- Davis (Syncfusion)